# Trying to get a text box in access to display the latest row in a query on button press

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have this code for the text box Control Source in Access:

```
=DLookUp("[Lot Number]","[Lot Number Generator Table Query]")
```

but that will only display the first row generated in the query. I need to get the latest one generated displayed. I've tried switching the ascending/descending order with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming LotNumber is sequential and that there are two tables to consider, try:

```
 =DLookUp("[Lot Number]","[Lot Number Generator Table Query]","[Lot Number]=" & 
  Dmax("[Lot Number]","[Some Table]"))
```

Or much more simply, if there is only one table:

```
 =Dmax("[Lot Number]","[Lot Number Generator Table Query]")
```

This is not safe in a multiuser environment or when Lot Number is an autonumber.

See also [Domain Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168244%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: That last bit seems to have gotten it. Thank you!